# Event to change font size if character counter greater then 100

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have this function where anytime a cell inside the specific range changes, calls a function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:L60")) Is Nothing Then
    Call fit_text
    End If
End Sub
```

The function fit_text changes the font size of the value of the active cell.

```
Sub fit_text()
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Characters.Count

    If ActiveCell.Characters.Count > 100 Then
        ActiveCell.Font.Size = 8
    Else
        ActiveCell.Font.Size = 10
    End If
End Sub
```

**PROBLEM:** whenever I change the value of a cell where the character count is bigger then 100, the font size remains 10 and the message box that tells the value of the count shows 0, but whenever I run it on vba the message box shows the correct value and changes the font size if the count is bigger then 100. I need it to be automatic. Can´t change the height or the width of the cells

Comment: Try `If Len(ActiveCell.Value) > 100 Then` and `MsgBox Len(ActiveCell.Value)`

Comment: Te same happends, the msgbx returns the value 0, but when I run it on vba it returns the correct value and changes the font size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Excel can automatically shrink the font size to fit into the cell. Therefore select your cell, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> go to the `Alignment` tab and select `Shrink To Fit`.

---

**To fix your code:**
Don't use `ActiveCell`. Use `Target` or the `Intersect` range instead. The `ActiveCell` might not be the cell that was changed. And also `Target` can be multiple cells so you need to loop through all the changed cells and test each cell individually.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A1:L60"))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange 'loop through all changed cells
            MsgBox Len(Cell.Value)

            If Len(Cell.Value) > 100 Then
                Cell.Font.Size = 8
            Else
                Cell.Font.Size = 10
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell` is the one active after the Change event. You can pass `Target` from the event to your method `fit_text`, so that it will always refer to the changed cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(target, Range("A1:L60")) Is Nothing Then
    Call fit_text(target)
    End If
End Sub


Sub fit_text(target As Range)
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
    MsgBox target.Characters.Count

'    If ActiveCell.Characters.Count > 100 Then
'        ActiveCell.Font.Size = 8
'    Else
'        ActiveCell.Font.Size = 10
'    End If

If target.Characters.Count > 100 Then
        target.Font.Size = 8
    Else
        target.Font.Size = 10
    End If
End Sub
```

You will also want to include a check for when Target is more than a single cell; in which case you will probably want your procedure to check each cell's content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 'ActiveCell'.

For example when you edit the Cell `A1` and press enter, the `ActiveCell` you are using in `fit_text` is not `A1`, but `A2`.

This however can easily fixed, by just passing the Cell from the `Worksheet_Change` to `fit_text`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:L60")) Is Nothing Then
        'Pass the Target to 'fit_text'
        Call fit_text(Target)
    End If
End Sub

Sub fit_text(Cell)
    'Instead of using ActiveCell, use Cell (which is the passed Target)
    MsgBox Cell.Characters.Count

    If Cell.Characters.Count > 100 Then
        Cell.Font.Size = 8
    Else
        Cell.Font.Size = 10
    End If
End Sub
```